# Got problem on SelectOptions on Multiple Products

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller, list, selectoption

I got products.

```
public List<ProntoEVents_Product__c> getProducts() {
        if(products == null) {

           products = [SELECT Id, Name, ProntoEvents_Product_Name__c, End_Date__c, Price__c, Quantity__c  FROM ProntoEvents_Product__c Where Event_Name__c = :eventId];
        }


        return products;
    }
```

This is how i display my product.

[image]

VF Page

```
<apex:repeat var="product" value="{!products}">
<tr>
 <td class="td-1">{!product.ProntoEvents_Product_Name__c}</td>
 <td>{!product.Quantity__c} Tickets</td>
 <td><apex:outputText value="{0,date,MM'/'dd'/'yyyy}">
 <apex:param value="{!product.End_Date__c}" /> 
 </apex:outputText></td>
<td>
 <apex:outputText >
 ${!IF((product.Price__c != null),product.Price__c,0)}
 </apex:outputText>
</td>
<td>
 <apex:form >
  <apex:selectList value="{!selectedVal}" size="1"> 
   <apex:selectOptions value="{!openPresentationOptions}" /> 
  </apex:selectList>
</apex:form>
</td>
</tr>                      
</apex:repeat>
```

Selectoptions for the quantity:

Controller

```
public String selectedVal{get;set;}
List<ProntoEvents_Product__c> products;

public List<SelectOption> getopenPresentationOptions(){

        if(products == null) {

           products = [SELECT Id,ProntoEvents_Product_Name__c,Minimum_Quantity__c,Maximum_Quantity__c  FROM ProntoEvents_Product__c Where Event_Name__c = :eventId];
        } 
        System.debug(products);

        List<SelectOption> optns = new List<Selectoption>();
        for(ProntoEvents_Product__c wew: products){

            for (Integer i = 0; i <= wew.Maximum_Quantity__c; i++) {

              System.debug('TEST -->'+wew.Maximum_Quantity__c);
            optns.add(new selectOption(wew.Id,String.valueOf(i)));
            }
            break;
        }


        return optns;
    }
```

Supposed to be the minimum and maximum quantity of each product(ticket) is different. Early bird maximum quantity is 15, General Admission is 20 and VIP Ticket is 10. That what supposed to be on dropdown. But my code output displays 1-15 only, meaning that it displays only the data from first product(ticket).

Is there any idea or solutions I can merge the product and the display of the  quantity? or How I can merge the List of products and SelectOptions of quantity?. Hope you get me.. thanks

Answer (score 3):

The reason you are getting only 0-15 is you used break in your for loop which will terminate the loop after executing it for first time.

You cannot get this to be done without using Wrapper class.

Controller:

```
public class Wrapper {
    public ProntoEvents_Product__c prod {get; set;}
    public List<SelectOption> quantityoption {get; set;}
}
public List<Wrapper> getProducts() { 
    List<Wrapper> lstwrap = new List<Wrap>();       
    for(ProntoEvents_Product__c prod : [SELECT Id, Name, ProntoEvents_Product_Name__c, End_Date__c, Price__c, Quantity__c  FROM ProntoEvents_Product__c Where Event_Name__c = :eventId]) {
        Wrapper w = new Wrapper();
        List<SelectOption> optns = new List<SelectOption>();
        for (Integer i = 0; i <= prod.Maximum_Quantity__c; i++) {
            System.debug('TEST -->'+prod.Maximum_Quantity__c);
            optns.add(new selectOption(String.valueOf(i),String.valueOf(i)));
        }
        w.prod = prod;
        w.quantityoption = optns;
        lstwrap.add(w);
    }
    return lstwrap;
}
```

Visualforce Page:

```
<apex:repeat var="product" value="{!products}">
    <tr>
        <td class="td-1">{!product.prod.ProntoEvents_Product_Name__c}</td>
        <td>{!product.prod.Quantity__c} Tickets</td>
        <td>
        <apex:outputText value="{0,date,MM'/'dd'/'yyyy}">
            <apex:param value="{!product.prod.End_Date__c}" /> 
        </apex:outputText>
        </td>
        <td>
        <apex:outputText >
        ${!IF((product.prod.Price__c != null),product.prod.Price__c,0)}
        </apex:outputText>
        </td>
        <td>
        <apex:form >
        <apex:selectList value="{!product.prod.Quantity__C}" size="1"> 
        <apex:selectOptions value="{!product.quantityoptions}" /> 
        </apex:selectList>
        </apex:form>
        </td>
    </tr>                      
</apex:repeat>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Currently you're going through all the products that you're listing and putting all the quantities into 1 and only select list (which is then used for each of the displayed products). You need to separate that and create a select list for each of the products individually. There are many options of how to do that, but the two that I can think of straight away are

1. Using a Map
2. Using a Wrapper Class

I think the map in this scenario would be easier to implement.

First thing you need to do is declare a map that will hold the product Id and it's related list of select options.

```
Map <Id, List <SelectOption>> productQuantitiesMap {get; private set;}
```

Then you'll need another map to keep the selected quantity for each of the products:

```
Map <Id, String> productSelectedQuantity {get; private set;}
```

Inside your constructor initialize these maps:

```
productQuantitiesMap = new Map <Id, List <SelectOption>> ();
productSelectedQuantity = new Map <Id, String> ();
```

Next step would be to populate these maps when loading all the products. You can do this inside your products getter method:

```
public List<ProntoEVents_Product__c> getProducts() {
    if(products == null) {
        products = [SELECT Id, Name, ProntoEvents_Product_Name__c, End_Date__c, Price__c, Quantity__c, Maximum_Quantity__c FROM ProntoEvents_Product__c Where Event_Name__c = :eventId];

        for (ProntoEvents_Product__c productRecord : products)
        {
            // set the default selected value
            productSelectedQuantity.put(productRecord.Id, "0"); // default to 0

            // populate the options for this product
            productQuantitiesMap.put(productRecord.Id, new List <SelectOption> ());
            for (Integer i = 0; i <= productRecord.Maximum_Quantity__c; i++)
            {
                productQuantitiesMap.get(productRecord.Id).add(new SelectOption(String.valueOf(i), String.valueOf(i)));
            }
        }
    }

    return products;
}
```

Then finally in your VisualForce page you can retrieve the options for each of the products as you iterate through via the existing `apex:repeat`:

```
<apex:repeat var="product" value="{!products}">
    <tr>
        <!-- your existing code -->
        <td>
            <apex:form >
                <apex:selectList value="{!productSelectedQuantity[product.Id]]}" size="1"> 
                    <apex:selectOptions value="{!productQuantitiesMap[product.Id}" /> 
                </apex:selectList>
            </apex:form>
        </td>
    </tr>
</apex:repeat>
```

I assume you'd have some kind of save method, so getting the selected quantity for each product would be simple. Iterate through each product and check it's quantity inside the map:

```
for (ProntoEvents_Product__c productRecord : products)
{
    system.debug('Current Product Name : ' + productRecord.ProntoEvents_Product_Name__c);
    system.debug('Current Product Selected Quantity : ' + productQuantitiesMap.get(productRecord.Id));
}
```

Comment: Beautiful, in the same time someone else just gave you an example of the 2nd option that I suggested :)